# Is it possible to search widget by name in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

If i create a widget in Tkinter i can specify a widget name that takes part in tcl/tk "widget path" concept. For example:

```
from Tkinter import *
button = Button( Frame( Tk(), name = "myframe" ), name = "mybutton" )
str( button ) == ".myframe.mybutton"
```

Is it possible to get a widget by it's name, "mybutton" in my example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, but you have to hold a reference to the root `Tk` instance: just use the `Tk.nametowidget()` method:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> win = Tk()
>>> button = Button( Frame( win, name = "myframe" ), name = "mybutton" )
>>> win.nametowidget("myframe.mybutton")
<Tkinter.Button instance at 0x2550c68>
```

Answer (score 8):

Every Tkinter widget has an attribute `children` which is a dictionary of `widget name`→`widget instance`. Given that, one can find any subwidget by:

```
widget.children['subwidget_name'].children['subsubwidget_name'] # ...
```

Comment: Instead of using `widget.children['foo']` you could use `widget.nametowidget('foo')` to not rely on the attribute dict. `nametowidget` is internally query-ing that attribute.