# How to reference correctly to frame names in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, reference, frame

I am creating a card game in tkinter and need help with referencing to the frame names. My problem is that when I want to "refresh" the frame, I need to destroy and recreate it and this changes the progressive numbering of the frames.

Please take a look at the code below. The example shows that the third frame every time gets a new name as it gets recreated.

```
import tkinter as tk


class RootFrame(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.main_window = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_window.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.main_label = tk.Label(self.main_window, text="Main Window")
        self.main_label.pack()

        self.second_frame = SecondFrame(self.main_window, self)
        self.second_frame.pack()


class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Second Frame")
        label.pack()

        self.create_third_frame()

    def create_third_frame(self):
        self.third_frame = ThirdFrame(self, self.controller)
        self.third_frame.pack()

    def update_frame(self):
        self.third_frame.destroy()
        self.create_third_frame()


class ThirdFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Third Frame")
        label.pack()

        refresh_button = tk.Button(
            self, text="Resfresh", command=self.parent.update_frame)
        refresh_button.pack()

        print(self.winfo_name())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = RootFrame()
    app.mainloop()
```

The code above is used to illustrate the problem. Please run the code and you'll see the changing widget name in the terminal.

I use `winfo_parent` and `winfo_name` in my actual code to create different conditions for button bindings. For example, if the user clicks a `widget1` in `frame6` happens X and when I click a `widget8` in `frame2` happens Y. This works until I `destroy()` and recreate something and everything breaks.

I suppose that using `winfo_name` and `winfo_parent` for this kind of referencing is not the correct way to get around, but I really can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but you can assign a specific name to the widget:

```
def create_third_frame(self):
    self.third_frame = ThirdFrame(self, self.controller, name='testframe')
    self.third_frame.pack()
```

Then each time the name of the frame created will be consistent.

You can also reference the widget by name with `Tk().nametowidget()`, see this relevant answer here: [Is it possible to search widget by name in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894841/is-it-possible-to-search-widget-by-name-in-tkinter#8895847)

> ```
> >>> from Tkinter import *
> >>> win = Tk()
> >>> button = Button( Frame( win, name = "myframe" ), name = "mybutton" )
> >>> win.nametowidget("myframe.mybutton")
> <Tkinter.Button instance at 0x2550c68>
> ```

I would recommend sticking with a OOP approach however, and just reference it with from your code like `self.thirdframes` where you might have a `list` or `dict` of `ThirdFrame` objects.  This way your python code can easily reference the objects without going back to the tcl interpreter and parse the widget name.  If you ever will only have one `ThirdFrame`, then just reference back to `self.thirdframe` whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In hindsight the solution seems so obvious. How could I not think of this by myself?

Comment: You're welcome.  Sometimes the most obvious things go woosh, it happens to the best of us.